# Cairo Dock: white outline on selected icons?

Tags: icons, dock, cairo

I installed Cairo Dock and it's working fine, but I'm seeing a white outline on selected icons. I've searched, but cannot find the file(s) associated with this outline. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on **cairo-dock** and select *cairo dock - configure*
2. Click <kbd>Advanced mode</kbd>

   [image: button is in bottom left of window]
3. Click **Indicators**

   [image: in Appearance section]
4. In the **Indicator of the active window** section, select *image* of the **Type of indicator** drop down.

   [image: config dialog]
5. You can select any image file to use as the active app indicator, or just leave it blank to *deactivate* it
6. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>

Comment: My Appearance menu is missing the `Indicators` app.  I see all the other options that you have in your picture except `Indicators`.  Can you tell me how to add this option to Cairo-Dock?

Comment: Thanks for your attention and answer to this question.  I was able to find the `Indicators` option by clicking on `Icons` in the appearance menu.  I'm adding an up vote for the usefulness of your answer.